# eAccelerator with two versions of PHP through FastCGI

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, php

Alright so I will outline how everything is setup and running for me on my dedicated box.  I have everything working accept eAccelerator only works on one of my PHP applications.

## Apache2

I have Apache2 setup and running with virtualhosts.  Apache has a file at `/etc/apache2/php-version-5.2.conf` which gets included on each vhost when it needs to run PHP 5.2:

```
#include for sites that still need to run at php 5.2.x

SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR /opt/php5.2/conf.d/
ScriptAlias /php5-cgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-cgi
Action application/x-httpd-php5 /php5-cgi

<FilesMatch "\.php">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php5 .php4 .php3 .phtml
```

## PHP

I have installed the latest version of PHP 5.3 from the Debian repo.  I also have a compiled version of PHP 5.2.17 sitting at `/opt/php5.2/`.  To compile PHP 5.2 and get fastcgi delivering to the appropriate PHP application [I followed these instructions](http://blog.breidert.net/php-5-2-and-php-5-3-for-drupal-applications-under-apache-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/).  This works as needed.

## eAccelerator

eAccelerator is working on PHP 5.3 from the Debian repo but I cannot get it to load on the compiled version of PHP 5.2.

I compiled from source for both PHP installs from [these instructions](https://github.com/eaccelerator/eaccelerator/wiki/InstallFromSource).

In `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/eaccelerator.ini` I have:

```
extension="eaccelerator.so"
eaccelerator.shm_size="16"
eaccelerator.cache_dir="/var/cache/eaccelerator"
eaccelerator.enable="1"
eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"
eaccelerator.debug="0"
eaccelerator.filter=""
eaccelerator.shm_max="0"
eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"
eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"
eaccelerator.shm_only="0"
eaccelerator.compress="1"
eaccelerator.compress_level="9"
```

In `/opt/php5.2/conf.d/eaccelerator.ini` I have:

```
;extension="/opt/php5.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so"
;zend_extension="/opt/php5.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so"
;zend_extension_ts="/opt/php5.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so"
;extension="eaccelerator.so"
eaccelerator.shm_size="16"
eaccelerator.cache_dir="/var/cache/eaccelerator-php-5.2"
eaccelerator.enable="1"
eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"
eaccelerator.debug="0"
eaccelerator.filter=""
eaccelerator.shm_max="0"
eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"
eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"
eaccelerator.shm_only="0"
eaccelerator.compress="1"
eaccelerator.compress_level="9"
```

## phpinfo();

The output of phpinfo(); on each site is as expected with the exception of eAccelerator not being enabled on the PHP 5.2 sites.  It is however enabled perfectly on the PHP 5.3 sites.

## Virtualhost config

Anytime I need a site to load PHP 5.2 I simply load the aforementioned php-version-5.2.conf file, otherwise the site defaults to PHP 5.3.

Comment: What [configure options](http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php) did you use when you compiled PHP from source? E.g. `--enable-fastcgi`.

Comment: I used `'./configure' '--prefix=/opt/php5.2' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/php5.2' '--with-mysqli' '--with-mysql' '--with-curl' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir' '--enable-cli' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-discard-path' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-zlib' `, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to uncomment the extension load? As shown, the extension is not loaded in /opt/php5.2/conf.d/eaccelerator.ini